# Why do intramolecular forces weaken due to heat?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

In my most recent research into thermoplastics, I was unable to find any information regarding what *actually* happens to intramolecular forces when heat is applied.

Comment: ***They don't weaken***. It is just that the molecules start to move faster, so you can't hold them in place using the same force as before.

Comment: You can think of intermolecular forces as having an anharmonic and dissociating potential , such as  Morse or Lennard -Jones. The potential will have vibrational energy levels and as heat is applied more of these levels become excited till eventually the dissociation limit is reached and the molecules separate. So the intermolecular 'bond' is weaker as energy is suppled as levels close to the dissociation limit are populated and this is also where the separation of molecules is larger.